# CM_Get_Device_Interface_List returns CR_INVALID_POINTER

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-phone-8.1, uwp, device

So, I have little problem with CM_Get_Device_Interface_List function. Function returns with error code 3, which is CR_INVALID_POINTER. But when I call CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_Size function, it returns success.

```
ULONG lenght = 0;
PWSTR DevicePath = NULL;
CONFIGRET cr = CR_SUCCESS;
cr = CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_Size(&lenght, (LPGUID)&HWN_DEVINTERFACE_NLED, NULL, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT);// success
if (cr != CR_SUCCESS) 
{
    // error handling
}
cr = CM_Get_Device_Interface_List((LPGUID)&HWN_DEVINTERFACE_NLED, NULL, DevicePath, lenght, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT); // error
if (cr != CR_SUCCESS)
{
    // error handling
}
DEFINE_GUID(HWN_DEVINTERFACE_NLED,
0x6b2a25e2, 0xaaf5, 0x482c, 0x99, 0xa5, 0x62, 0x05, 0xcd, 0xcc, 0x17, 0x6a); // GUID Declaration
```

So, why the pointer is invalid?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, probably figured this out but in case someone else comes across this I believe the reason you are getting the invalid pointer is because you are passing in a null pointer as the buffer (DevicePath), it must be allocated with the size returned from your first call.

**Example (cleaned up a bit):**

```
ULONG bufferSize = 0;

if (CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_Size(&bufferSize, (LPGUID)&HWN_DEVINTERFACE_NLED, NULL, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT) == CR_SUCCESS)
{
    PWSTR buffer = (PWSTR)malloc(bufferSize);

    if (CM_Get_Device_Interface_List((LPGUID)&HWN_DEVINTERFACE_NLED, NULL, buffer, bufferSize, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT) == CR_SUCCESS)
    {
        // buffer should now contain a list of NULL-terminated unicode strings
    }

    if (buffer)
    {
        free(buffer);
    }
}


DEFINE_GUID(HWN_DEVINTERFACE_NLED,
0x6b2a25e2, 0xaaf5, 0x482c, 0x99, 0xa5, 0x62, 0x05, 0xcd, 0xcc, 0x17, 0x6a); // GUID Declaration
```

**Alternate Example (no malloc):**

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 4096 // 4k buffer should be plenty

WCHAR buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

if (CM_Get_Device_Interface_List((LPGUID)&HWN_DEVINTERFACE_NLED, NULL, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT) == CR_SUCCESS)
{
    // buffer should now contain a list of NULL-terminated unicode strings
}

DEFINE_GUID(HWN_DEVINTERFACE_NLED,
0x6b2a25e2, 0xaaf5, 0x482c, 0x99, 0xa5, 0x62, 0x05, 0xcd, 0xcc, 0x17, 0x6a); // GUID Declaration
```